# In TypeScript is there a way to import or export modules that span a set of files?

Tags: node.js, module, typescript

Say I have a directory structure like so.

```
Shapes
  |__Square.ts
  |__Circle.ts
  |__Triangle.ts
```

And an example of Square.ts below which exports Square. From what I understand this makes it an external module.

*Square.ts*

```
export class Square {
    constructor(private width: number, private height: number) {
    }
}
```

Is there a way in TypeScript to import/export all Shapes defined in these files without having to specifically reference them.

Example Import: `import * as Shapes from "./Shapes"`

Example Export: `export * from "./Shapes"`

So far reading through GitHub issues and the available documentation on the TypeScript language or the **tsc** compiler I have been unable to find an answer to whether this is possible or not. In my particular case I'm interested in this behavior in Node.js which supports [folders as modules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_folders_as_modules) and perhaps bundlers like Webpack may have a similar mechanism.

Related:

- [With latest TypeScript, you may not need Webpack](https://medium.com/@vivainio/with-latest-typescript-you-may-not-need-webpack-417d2ef0e773#.k17548cen)
- [TypeScript Handbook - Splitting Across Files](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#modules-splitting-across-files)
- https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17
- https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_folders_as_modules